# ISO-8859-1 character set in SQS message

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have below message in AWS SQS.

```
    {
  "test": {
    "testData": "kökkö" 
  }
}
```

And  I am trying to read the message using below code.

```
ReceiveMessageRequest receiveMessageRequest = new ReceiveMessageRequest(url)
                        .withWaitTimeSeconds(10)
                        .withMaxNumberOfMessages(10);
                List<Message> messageFromSqs = amazonSQS.receiveMessage(receiveMessageRequest).getMessages();
                if (Objects.nonNull(messageFromSqs) && !messageFromSqs.isEmpty()) {

                    for (Message messages : messageFromSqs) {
                        String requestBody = messages.getBody();
                        System.out.println(requestBody);    
                    }
```

After reading this message encoded in as “kÃ¶kkÃ¶" .I have tried multiple way to decode but it’s not decoding and it’s remains same.

And the same code when I tried in windows there I am able to decode and able to decode as original (kökkö) ; but issue in I am getting in Linux platform.

Kindly suggest me how  do the perform the decoding in Linux platform.

Comment: Presumable this protocol is carried over HTTP?  Then I imagine you have to declare the encoding in an HTTP header.  By the time it is converted to a Java String value, it's too late to be concerned about how it was encoded on the wire.

Comment: I am unable to add header here since , I  am reading the message from SQS.And there is no option to add header

Comment: Unless you can intercede at the point before the byte-stream becomes a String, there seems little you can do.  Java Strings **are** UTF-16.  Why are you intent on using an old code like ISO-8859-1, though?  Why not UTF-8?  Are you sure it's using 8859-1?

Comment: I think the chances are high that there is no 8859-1 encoding in use, that text in the message is Unicode throughout, and your problem is simply that you're attempting to print the string in a terminal that cannot handle UTF-8.  You should attempt to distinguish "what is in the String" from "marks appearing in a terminal".

Comment: Even I have tried to encode using UTF-8 ,but getting the same issue. But same thing working my windows machine. Not sure what is going when i am deploying the code in Linux machine and there encoding not working.

Comment: Print out the numerical value of each char in requestBody:  `for (int j=0; j<requestBody.length(); j++) System.out.printf("%x  ", (int) requestBody.charAt(j));` and post the output in your question. Then we can see what we are actually dealing with.

Comment: Find something in the SQS API that lets you get an InputSteam for the body, then decorate that with an InputStreamReader, which will allow you to specify the charset.